# How to prompt for sim selection before sending an SMS in dual sim phones using SMS manager programmatically?

Tags: android, sms, smsmanager

> How to find SubscriptionId by prompting sim selection?

```
 SmsManager smsManager = null;
                   if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
                     smsManager = SmsManager.getSmsManagerForSubscriptionId();
                   }else{
                       smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                   }`
```

subcription id needed inside `getSmsManagerForSubscriptionId()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `subscriptionManagerObj.getActiveSubscriptionInfoList()` to get subscriptionIds based on Sim Slot. Based on the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SubscriptionManager#getactivesubscriptioninfolist)

> Get the SubscriptionInfo(s) of the currently inserted SIM(s). **The
>   records will be sorted by getSimSlotIndex() then by getSubscriptionId()**

```
 SmsManager smsManager = null;
 if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {

    SubscriptionManager subscriptionManager = (SubscriptionManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SUBSCRIPTION_SERVICE);
    List<SubscriptionInfo> subscriptionInfoList=subscriptionManager.getActiveSubscriptionInfoList();
    int subId = subscriptionInfoList.get(0).getSubscriptionId();// change index to 1 if you want to get Subscrption Id for slot 1.
    smsManager = SmsManager.getSmsManagerForSubscriptionId(subId);

 }else{
      smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
 }
```

Comment: How to change sim index 0 to 1 by prompting sim selection dialogview.I want ask every time prompt sim selection before send sms

Comment: You can have Spinner/EditText in your dialog to take the input. Then in onClickListener, you can retrieve the selected information and pass it to current code

Comment: Is there any other process to open sim selection through Intent or else?

Comment: So far no official API/Intent available. You have to do it by yourself by implementing custom view